# Fatal error: Call to a member function getTelephone() on boolean in /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, paypal-express

I am using `Magento 1.9.1.0`. Below mentioned error happen after payment made by using paypal express checkout.

Steps 1: Register and add a product to cart

Steps 2: Give the Billing Information & Payment Information -Paypal Express Checkout

Steps 3:  Make payment

after Pay now button click page shows like this:-

Fatal error: Call to a member function `getTelephone()` on boolean in `/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` on line 1293

Refresh

Unable to initialize Express Checkout.

Error occurred line in this function:-

```
    public function getShippingCarrier()
{
    $carrierModel = $this->getData('shipping_carrier');
    if (is_null($carrierModel)) {
        $carrierModel = false;
        /**
         * $method - carrier_method
         */
        $method = $this->getShippingMethod(true);
        if ($method instanceof Varien_Object) {
            $className = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/' . $method->getCarrierCode() . '/model');
            if ($className) {
                $carrierModel = Mage::getModel($className);
            }  // error occured line
        }
        $this->setData('shipping_carrier', $carrierModel);
    }
    return $carrierModel;
}
```

how to rectify this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried lot and finally find a solution. Already existing user doesn't happen  in this error (Fatal error: Call to a member function getTelephone() on boolean in

> /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php

on line 1293)  Newly registered user with first order only failed after that next orders working properly.

In registration page:

- First Name
- Last Name
- Email Address
- Password & Confirm password.

**Solution:-**

> Additionally, I added Billing address after that it's newly added user
>   with first order and next orders working fine.

How to add billing addressing in registration page.
There are two methods:-
Method 1:-
Steps:

> /app/design/frontend/{packagetheme}/default/template/persistent/customer/form/registration.phtml

Add the below given code

```
<?php $this->setShowAddressFields(true); ?> //for billing address show
```

before,

```
<?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
```

Now,look like this,

```
 <?php $this->setShowAddressFields(true); ?>  
 <?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
```

Method 2:-

Steps:

> /app/design/frontend/{packagetheme}/default/layout/customer.xml

– Add inside customer_account_create node:

```
<action method="setShowAddressFields"><value>true</value></action>
```

Now,look like this in xml page,

```
<customer_account_create translate="label"> <label>Customer Account Registration Form</label> <!-- Mage_Customer --> <remove name="right"/> <remove name="left"/>   <reference name="root">
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action> </reference> <reference name="content">
<block type="customer/form_register" name="customer_form_register" template="customer/form/register.phtml">
<action method="setShowAddressFields"><value>true</value></action>
<block type="page/html_wrapper" name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
<label>Form Fields Before</label>
</block>
</block> 
</reference> </customer_account_create>
```

By anyone method you can add billing address in registration page.